# Variable cannot be resolved in an If-Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I'm trying to do the below tutorial question.

```
// Create a method called greatestCommonFactor
// It should return the greatest common factor
// between two numbers.  
//
// Examples of greatestCommonFactor:
//   greatestCommonFactor(6, 4)   // returns 2
//   greatestCommonFactor(7, 9)   // returns 1
//   greatestCommonFactor(20, 30) // returns 10
//
// Hint: start a counter from 1 and try to divide both
// numbers by the counter. If the remainder of both divisions
// is 0, then the counter is a common factor. Continue incrementing
// the counter to find the greatest common factor. Use a while loop
// to increment the counter.
```

And my code is below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Ex4_GreatestCommonFactor {

    // This is the main method that is executed as
    // soon as the program starts.  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call the greatestCommonFactor method a few times and print the results
    }

    public static int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b){
        int i = 1 ;
        while (i >= 1 ){
            i++;
        }
        if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){
            ArrayList factor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            factor.add(i);  
        }
        else if (a%i <= 1 || b%i <= 1){
            Collections.sort(factor);
            List<Integer> topnum = factor.subList(factor.size() - 1, factor.size());

        }
        return topnum;
    }
}
```

So I have 2 questions.

1) In my elseif statement, I get an error where `factor` cannot be resolved to a variable. How do I "carry over" the `factor` ArrayList from the previous If statement into this elseif statement?

2) I also get a similar error where `topnum` cannot be resolved. Is this also a placement error for this line of code in my method, or am I making a completely different mistake?

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> factor = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: I'm a little bit concerned about the first four lines of your method.  What do you think happens to `i` if you start it at `1`, and then increase it until it's no longer `>= 1`?  And why do you do this?

Comment: That while loop will not end

Comment: It will end.  There are only finitely many `int` values.

Comment: @Ghokun It will end when the variable overflows.

Comment: Ofcourse it will end with overflow that was sarcasm. I actually wanted to warn about bracket placement of while loop.

Comment: The "scope" of a local variable declaration is only within the enclosing `{}` characters.  If you want a variable to be visible in a larger scope you must declare it in a larger scope.

Comment: @Ghokun when explaining technical details to a beginner, sarcasm is often a poor pedagogical strategy.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well I was thinking the while loop would end upon the return of `topnum` (i.e ending the loop when the highest common factor is found) I guess I'm doing it wrong? How should I go about correcting for this?

Comment: There's not really enough space in this comment field to teach you how to use while loops.  Fortunately, Oracle have a [tutorial online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable (amongst other 'parts' of java) has a scope, in which it is available.
The scope is usually the block in which the variable is declared.

Block: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

In your method greatestCommonFactor there are three variables, which are valid in the whole method:
a, b, i

You can access them everywhere from the start of you method (the first open brace) till the end of it (the last close brace).

The block inside your first if statement is an new scope. factor is declared in this scope and is no longer available, after program execution leaves this block.

```
    if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){                       // Start of Block/Scope
        ArrayList factor = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Declaration, you can access factor now
        factor.add(i);  
    }                                                // End of Block/Scope, factor inaccessible
```

The else if part is an new block with it's own scope.

```
    else if (a%i <= 1 || b%i <= 1){
        Collections.sort(factor);
        List<Integer> topnum = factor.subList(factor.size() - 1, factor.size());

    }
```

factor, being declared in the first block does not exists any more.
You could pull up the declaration and put it outside the if.

```
public static int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b){
    int i = 1 ;
    while (i >= 1 ){
        i++;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> factor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){
        factor.add(i);  
    }
    else if (a%i <= 1 || b%i <= 1){
        Collections.sort(factor);
        List<Integer> topnum = factor.subList(factor.size() - 1, factor.size());

    }
    return topnum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1) In my elseif statement, I get an error where factor cannot be resolved to a variable. How do I "carry over" the factor ArrayList from the previous If statement into this elseif statement?

by declaring it before if

```
ArrayList factor = null;
if ( /* some condition */ ) {
   // initialize factor
} else if (/* some condition */) {
  // access factor here
}
```

Comment: Generally one should **not** assign `null` to the variable in the above case, but allow the compiler to warn you if it is not assigned a value along all paths through the `if/else` statements.

Comment: While in this case (initialize in if, access in else if, assuming a loop around it) the compiler would not let you compile the code, because it is not guaranteed, that the variable will be initialized before it will be accessed.